# How to set the percentage height/width of child views of PercentFrameLayout at runtime

Tags: android

I want to set the child view's height/width of PercentFrameLayout programmatically. How to set the percentage height/width of child views of PercentFrameLayout at runtime..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you have View with Id view_child inside of your PercentLayout.

so use this code snippet

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view_child);
PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =(PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
// This will currently return null, if view not exist in your xml.
PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
info.heightPercent = 0.60;
view.requestLayout();
```

hope this help..

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView child= new ImageView(getActivity());

percentRelativeLayout.addView(child);

PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();

info.heightPercent = 0.05f;
info.widthPercent = 0.05f;
info.leftMarginPercent = 0.5f;
child.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this. But for me PercentLayoutInfo is always returning null. Do you know why?