# Different Cell size grid for custom views

Tags: android, view, android-gridview, dynamically-generated, android-gridlayout

I'm working on a project where I need to implement a grid to display "Widgets" (Custom made Views), reordered dynamically by the final user. More or less **the same as Android Launchers and their widgets**, Widgets that can be moved through the grid by the user (With long press, like most Launchers). Here is a preview of what I'm looking for:
[Every color represents one different kind of "Widget"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haiuL.png)

I've tried with GridLayout and TableLayout, but I'm not able to "merge" cells to adjust the layout to the Widget.

The grid itself is an 8 x 12 cells grid, where Widgets can use more than 1 cell each, for example, I've configured a "Widget button" that is 2 x 3 (h | w).

Is there any layout that fits what I need or I must create my own one?

Thank you, Abel!

Comment: Have you looked at PercentRelativeLayout?

Comment: It looks promising! I'll try to configure something and comment again!
**EDIT:** I tried to configure PercentRelativeLayout childs percentage in Java, but it seems (looking at the examples I found: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497833/how-to-set-the-percentage-height-width-of-child-views-of-percentframelayout-at-r)), percentage can only be settle with java if the child View is defined using XML. I need to create and position objects dynamically, just the same as Launcher Widgets.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code to programmatically create views and set up their `PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams` :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_percent_relative);

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.perecent_layout_view);

    View blueWidget = new View(this);
    blueWidget.setBackground(blue);
    root.addView(blueWidget);

    setUpLayout(blueWidget, 2.0f/8.0f, 6.0f/8.0f, 6.0f/8.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f/8.0f, 0.0f);

    View redWidget = new View(this);
    redWidget.setBackground(red);
    root.addView(redWidget);

    setUpLayout(redWidget, 5.0f/8.0f, 2.0f/8.0f, 3.0f/8.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f/8.0f);

}

private void setUpLayout(View view, float widthPercent, 
                         float heightPercent,
                         float leftMarginPercent, 
                         float rightMarginPercent,
                         float topMarginPercent, 
                         float bottomMarginPercent) {

    PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
    PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo percentLayoutInfo = layoutParams.getPercentLayoutInfo();

    percentLayoutInfo.heightPercent = heightPercent;
    percentLayoutInfo.widthPercent = widthPercent;
    percentLayoutInfo.topMarginPercent= topMarginPercent;
    percentLayoutInfo.bottomMarginPercent= bottomMarginPercent;
    percentLayoutInfo.leftMarginPercent= leftMarginPercent;
    percentLayoutInfo.rightMarginPercent= rightMarginPercent;

    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

}
```

The view looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I mark this one as the correct answer because it seems perfectly valid for what I've asked, but I think i found a way to do it with a simple GridLayout and some arrays for managing positions. I'll post it here if finally it works.
Thank you!

Comment: When you post your solution feel free to mark it as the correct one.  I wanted to demonstrate that you can use the layout programmatically and get the behavior you wanted.

Comment: @sajunt4 Could you please post your solution with GridLayout ...

Answer (score 1):

can your app make do with a staggeredGridLayout with a recycler view? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

all column size has to be the same though... kinda like the following [image]

taken from this example https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: Mmm... The column size should be variable too, so I think is not the best option... I'm gonna look at this, but it doesn't seem to fit with what i 

Anyway, thank you for your support!